# Change a rcParams keymap to right mouse click?

Tags: python, events, matplotlib

Is it possible to change a keymap of the plt.rcParams dictionary to a mouse click?

What I'm trying to do is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.rcParams['keymap.zoom'] = 'z' # works
plt.rcParams['keymap.back'] = 'Button-3' # doesn't work

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot([1,2,3],[1,2,3])

plt.show()
```

I was wondering if the problem is the `'Button-3'` string. If it is, what should be the correct call for the right mouse button?

Comment: Not sure this is possible as the rcparams keymap is used to set up a key board event handler, not a mouse event handler.